# c++ reverse Array elements using dynamic Allocation Operators

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse, dynamic-memory-allocation

Hi i'm the beginner of c++.
This time, I try to reverse Array 's element-order using dynamic Allocation Operator. 
For example an array{1,2,3,4} will be rearranged {4,3,2,1} through calling function 'reverseArray'.
Everything works fine but somehow i got unwanted integer '-1' along with rearranged Array.
For example {-1,4,3,2,1}.
It means i did wrong and i really want to learn my fault.
Here is my code, please help me to figure out.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<new>

using namespace std;

void reverseArray(int [] , int);

int main(){

    int num=0;

    cout << "enter size of pointer : " ;
    cin >> num ;

    int *pointerArray = new int [num];

    cout << "enter integer numbers in pointer" << endl;

    for(int index = 0 ; index < num ; index++){
        cin >> pointerArray[index];     
    }

    reverseArray(pointerArray, num);

delete[] pointerArray;
    return 0 ; 
}

void reverseArray(int reverse[], int Size){
    int*ptArray[Size]; 

    cout << "the reverse order of entered numbers is : " << endl;
    for(int index = 0 ; Size >= 0 ; index++) {
        ptArray[index] = &reverse[Size];
        cout << *ptArray[index] << " " ;
        --Size; 
    }

    return ; 
}
```

Comment: why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: `int*ptArray[Size];` uses VLA extension, and so is not valid C++.

Comment: you start the loop with `Size = size of the array` and loop until `Size == 0` (inclusively), this makes `size of array +1` total iterations.

Comment: With 0-indexing, you have to iterate from 0 to n-1 (inclusive), and for backward traversal, from n-1 to 0

Comment: If the 2nd argument to `reverseArray` is the actual size of the `reverse[]` array, then accessing `reverse[Size]` in your loop will start one beyond the array - and is thus *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: You can use vector and reverse iterator instead of this code.

Comment: dont be mislead into thinking that c-arrays are for beginners and `std::vector` is advanced, it is the opposite. Also using `new` isnt really beginner friendly

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 You're correct, of course. But lot of times, questions like this come from homework assignments where the students are learning how memory works, and have to use the techniques taught in class.

Comment: @parktomatomi that might be the case, but that wont stop me from suggesting `std::vector`, because too often ppl are thaught "how memory works" without ever being told that in any other situation you would choose a different solution

Comment: When there's better tool for the job, you make the suggestion and let the asker make the decision to use it or not.Often the right way comes down to, "I can't use `std::whatever` so I'll make my own version!" Folks who make that jump learn an order of magnitude more from the assignment than their classmates.

Comment: @Jarod42  thank you i should aware of it that i set the initial index with '0'

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes should think about reverse[Size] when it reversed thank you :)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 i didn't learn anything about vector. it might be sound non-sense though. :) but thanks for the tips. i will search for the vector operator

Comment: @user4581301 haha i will try to break the nutshell :D at college profs don't teach even technical thing. so have to figure it out with myself&books&stackoverflow thank you btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function

```
void reverseArray(int reverse[], int Size){
    int*ptArray[Size]; 

    cout << "the reverse order of entered numbers is : " << endl;
    for(int index = 0 ; Size >= 0 ; index++) {
        ptArray[index] = &reverse[Size];
        cout << *ptArray[index] << " " ;
        --Size; 
    }

    return ; 
}
```

does not make sense.

For starters variable length arrays

```
    int*ptArray[Size];
```

is not a standard C++ feature.

Secondly in this loop

```
    for(int index = 0 ; Size >= 0 ; index++) {
        ptArray[index] = &reverse[Size];
        cout << *ptArray[index] << " " ;
        --Size; 
    }
```

there is access beyond the arrays.

For example let's assume that `Size` is equal to `1`.
In this case within the ,loop we have

```
ptArray[0] = &reverse[1];
```

and then

```
ptArray[1] = &reverse[0];
```

However the only valid index for such arrays is 0.

It is unclear what you are trying to do.

If you want to reverse an array in place then the function can look like

```
void reverseArray( int a[], size_t Size )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < Size / 2; i++ )
    {
        // you can use the standard function std::swap here
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[Size - i - 1];
        a[Size - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

And in main after calling the function you can output the reversed array .

Pay attention to that there is standard algorithm std::reverse that can do the rask.

You could just write

```
std::reverse( reverse, reverse + num );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void reverseArray( int a[], size_t Size )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < Size / 2; i++ )
    {
        // you can use the standard function std::swap here
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[Size - i - 1];
        a[Size - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    int *a = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    reverseArray( a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::reverse( a, a + N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete [] a;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you access the array out-of-bounds on the very first iteration, because for an array of size `Size` valid indices are `0` up to `Size-1`

It is not clear why you create an array of pointers, and `int*ptArray[Size];` is a variable lenght array (VLA) which is not standard C++. Further, you do not need to include `<new>`.

To print a dynamically sized (ie size is taken from input) array you would use a `std::vector` and a loop:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){   
    size_t size;
    std::cout << "enter size: ";
    std::cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> data(size);
    for (auto& element : data) std::cin >> element;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << data[ data.size()-1-i ]; // first element printed is data[data.size()-1]
    }    
}
```

If you want to reverse the array, not just print it in reverse order, there is `std::reverse` in `<algorithm>`. The algorithm also works with dynamically allocated arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){   
    size_t size;
    std::cout << "enter size: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    int* data = new int[size];
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i) std::cin >> data[i];

    std::reverse(data,data+size);
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i) std::cout << data[i];

    delete [] data;
}
```

Comment: thank you i will try with the vector :)) didn't know there are so many way to solve this questions :))

Comment: i know it's late to ask you a question. But if you are still interested in my question plz can you answer? in this statement ->std::reverse(data,data+size); can i understand like               
data ==data[0], because pointer variable 'data' allocated dynamic array?  sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: @HyeJinJang c-arrays can decay to pointers to their first element

Answer (score 0):

#include
using namespace std;

int main() {

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int temp=n;

int rem=0;
int i=0;


while (n>0) {



    n= n/10;
    i++;

}

int *arr = new int(i);

i=0;

while (temp>0) {

    rem=temp%10;
    arr[i]=rem;


    i++;

    temp= temp/10;



}
int t=0;

while(t<i) {
    cout<<arr[t]<<" ";
    t++;
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).