# In the reverse array function, declare the size of the array as a variable using template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, reverse, dynamic-memory-allocation

[I checked "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard". I know The latest version of the compiler can declare an array as a variable. But what I'm not sure about is ,in past versions of compilers, why `new T[b];` works , but `T Temp[b];` doesn't work.]

Are both 'Temp[b];' and 'T*temp = new T[b];' declared as variables? I don't know the difference between the two.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void reverseArray(T a[], int b) {
    T temp[b];

    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        temp[b - 1 - j] = a[j];

    for (int k = 0; k < b; k++)
        a[k] = temp[k];
}

int main() {
    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    reverseArray(x, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << x[i] << " ";
}
```

To explain the codes
I have a problem in `T temp[b];`

**Error Code**

> C2131 - expression did not evaluate to a constant //line6 ,
> C3863 - array type 'type' is not assignable //line6

The above code builds well on online C++ compilers in 'https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler ' but it doesn't build in my computer's visual studio (V.S Community 2019 ver_16.8.2)

I searched for the reason. The reason is that ,in the previous version of C++11, it is impossible to declare the size of the array as a variable. The size of the array must be determined at the time of compile in the previous version of C++11

So, the error-correction method that I found was

`1`. T temp[b]; --> T* temp = new T[b]; //line6

Use dynamic array

`2`.

```
template <class T>
void reverseArray(T a[], int b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < b / 2; i++) {
        T temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[b - 1 - i];
        a[b - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}
```

[Method2 Reference: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330094/c-reverse-array-elements-using-dynamic-allocation-operators" used the algorithm in this address]

It works well by using above two methods in my V.S

But what i don't understand is that ,in method 1, is the size of the array(new T[b]) declared as variable? I don't know the difference from the code that I wrote first.

In array `T Temp[b];` there is an error in my code because b is a variable. In `new T[b];` , likewise, b is a variable too.

Please explain the difference between my first code and method 1. How the algorithm works

Comment: `T temp[b];` defines a variable-length array, and [C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Use `std::vector` instead. I heartily recommend investing in [a good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or two.

Comment: `new T[b]` is not an array, its' an **expression** which allocates a dynamic array. Those are allowed to have variable size, regular arrays are not.

Comment: The questions you are asking are basic information about arrays, pointers, dynamic allocation and syntax. These are big topics which need a proper explanation, more explanation than can be given on a site like this. You should get a [book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282) and start studying. C++ cannot be learned by google.

Comment: It's also easy to reverse an array in place without using a temporary or just use `std::reverse`

Comment: Stop using "C" style arrays please, In C++ use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or std::array) + [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).  If you don't have access to a book then use https://www.learncpp.com/.